# How to change x-axis and y-axis position in BarChart (React Native)

Tags: react-native, bar-chart, react-native-chart-kit

I am new to React Native. I would like to know if we can change the position of X-Axis and Y-Axis into something like this (please refer to the picture I have attached below)

[image: Sample BarChart]

As you can see from the above image, Manager is an x-axis while sales refer as a y-axis. I am currently using 'BarChart' from 'react-native-chart-kit'.

Answer (score 0):

It would be great to see your code for how you've built this out in `react-native-chart-kit`, but I think it would be (as a best case scenario) as straightforward as using the names as `labels`, and the sales amounts as part of the `dataset`.

Per the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-chart-kit), it would probably look something like this for your graph:

```js
const data = {
  labels: ["John", "Jake", "Peter", "James", "Mary"],
  datasets: [
    {
      data: [10000, 12000, 13000, 10000, 9000]
    }
  ]
};
```

Where the indices of the labels and the data are lined up together, and you would use that as the `data` prop when using the `BarChart` component.

Comment: I guess OP require the label on the left side which default chart kit bar chart, label is display on bottom.